# What's the point of an inheritance tax on movable property? Can't valuable property be shipped to a country without the tax, and be inherited there?

Tags: international, tax-law, rental-property, inheritance, federal-tax-law

This probably wouldn't happen for property that's low value and bulky, like furniture. But for property like yachts, planes, artwork, jewellery, etc., it seems easy to move it to a country without inheritance taxes since the relocation costs would only be a small percentage of the total value.

Am I missing something here?

(I know the U.S. has a special law to tax overseas citizen, which almost no other country has. But the inheritance tax system predates that, and international travel was still straightforward back then for those with means.)

EDIT: Originally mentioned luxury cars but then realized it isn’t a good example as cars need to be legally imported back into the country, and thus pay import taxes, to be useful. This doesn’t apply to planes or yachts though in countries that allow foreign flagged yachts or foreign registered planes to operate. Personal items such as jewellery would probably also not have any import taxes imposed when the heir brings them back.

Comment: The point of *all* taxes is either to restrict behavior (making it expensive to do things that the government doesn't want to outright prohibit) or to generate revenue. Clearly, the point is to generate revenue. Are you really asking what the point is?

Comment: One thing that isn't being discussed is customs taxes. Often moving property out side a country for tax purposes (as opposed to just temporary removal that would not change the inheritance tax situation) results in customs duties that are higher than the inheritance tax would be.

Comment: @user6726 I'm asking why it exists for valuable, movable, property if it seems like it could be trivially circumvented?

Comment: @user1937198 Really? Which country has customs taxes for exporting personal property?

Comment: Personal items are not generally exempt from import duties. That is why for high-value jewellery it is often recommended to obtain a certificate before leaving for a trip and coming back. Exemptions exists for the relocation of immigrants and temporary residents, but countries often have different treatments of former residents.

Comment: Have a look e.g. at customs procedures for cars. You won't get it registered there without those papers, and without that registration it will be a domestic car from the inheritance tax office's point of view (it may still be afterwards, but before it will be for sure). While I don't know them, I'm sure prodedures are also in place for ships and airplanes.

Comment: Very few countries have export taxes that are relevant, but you have to take the property to a different country (import taxes) and then you probably want to bring them back (import taxes) for example for UK/EU importing is 20% of the value for cars/ships every time you switch tax residency from one to the other.

Comment: @user1937198 You make a point with cars, which by their nature, need to be registered. So I edited my question.

Comment: For foriegn flagged yachts, they remain tax resident in the country of which they are flagged, regardless of where they are located. So you can't move them for the purposes of inheritance taxes without changing the flag.

Comment: @user1937198 It seems trivial to change the flag of a yacht a few months before?

Comment: @M.Y.Zuo Changing the flag usually triggers tax residency, so you would have to pay import duties at the point of changing flag before and after, which would likely end up wiping out any savings in inheritance taxes. The only real way of taking advantage of this is to do what a lot of super-yachts and commercial international cargo ships do, which is permanently flag the vessel in a tax haven like jersey or panama, but this isn't seen as worth the hassle for smaller vessels (professional fees to handle the registration would cost more than the tax savings).

Answer (score 10):

In [germany](/questions/tagged/germany) inheritance tax (Erbschaftsteuer) taxes someone *receiving* an inheritance (or a gift - they are treated the same).
If the heir is (inheritance tax) resident in Germany, German inheritance tax is due in principle on the whole received property, regardless of where that property is.

- Paid foreign inheritance tax on particular types of property and in accordance with tax treaties can be deducted. (Details: see [§21 ErbStG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/erbstg_1974/__21.html) and [§121 BewG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/bewg/__121.html))

  *Wrt the scenario in the question: if that foreign country collects low/no inheritance tax, the heir gets accordingly low or no deduction from the due German inheritance tax.*
- Whether the "more mobile" property in the question counts as foreign property or not depends on whether the deceased was German resident in the sense of inheritance tax law or not (e.g. moved their residence to the foreign country > 5a before their death), but again, that wouldn't lower the total amount of taxes due, it only shifts who gets them.

In order to actually avoid German inheritance tax on the mobile property of the question, the heir would need to move their tax residency away from Germany.

Comment: In general, the term "inheritance tax" usually means a tax on a person receiving a gift, while an "estate tax" is a tax on the assets of a person who has died prior to its distribution to heirs and devisees.

Comment: @ohwilleke That is not true in England and Wales.  The current Inheritance Tax has to be paid by the estate before probate is granted (unless it is deferred to allow the sale of real property).

Comment: It seems trivial though for the wealthy German heir to stay for 183 days, or however long the exact cutoff is, in whichever foreign country that has no tax and then inherit the movable property there?

Comment: @M.Y.Zuo: Sure it's trivial: since the wall fell, all Germans are free to leave Germany, even permanently. However, see https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/erbstg_1974/__2.html: the heir needs to have stayed permanently outside Germany without any German residence for > 5 a before the death in question. And make sure neither they nor anyone else in their household has a German employer. Once that is achieved, only the listed property types if inside Germany will be taxed in Germany.

Comment: In addition to the uncertainty when to start those 5 years, the wealthy heir may find it cheaper to instead e.g. use the zero-tax option for the family home - which is available only if they permanently reside in said family home for the next 10 years.

Answer (score 7):

In the United States, inheritance taxes don't depend on the location of the property. They depend on the location where the estate was probated.

Usually inheritance taxes are only state taxes and are applied in the state where the person was resident at the time of their death. However, if the total value of the estate exceeds $12 million, then there is a Federal inheritance tax as well.

Comment: How does this address the scenario of someone close to death having all their valuable, movable, property moved overseas?

Comment: @If the property is part of their estate and they are an American citizen, it does not matter where the property is physically located. What matters is where the person is resident.

Comment: @M.Y.Zuo Cirero is close, but not quite right. The venue of a primary probate proceeding is based upon the domicile of the person who died without regard to citizenship. A non-U..S. citizen who resides, for example, in Boston, still has their estate probated in MA. Also, if someone not domiciled in a state has tangible property (real or personal) located physically in a state or intangible property that takes state intervention (like a right to a state income tax refund) the property in that state is subject to ancillary probate there even if the decedent isn't domiciled there re those assets.

Comment: @ohwilleke Ahh the usual US approach, you live here and have property elsewhere? We tax you. You live elsewhere and have property here? We tax you too. At least in the US the taxes tend to be bearable, in the EU we're learning this approach and the taxes are high.

Comment: @ohwilleke I don't quite get how that works for a US citizen close to death moving their property overseas to be inherited by a non-U.S. citizen a few months later. How exactly does the U.S. collect taxes on the non U.S. citizen heir in another country?

Comment: @DRF This particular part is not specific to the U.S. Many if not most countries combine residency-based taxation for incomes and location-based taxation for properties, and a mixed approach for probate. The particularity of the U.S. is citizenship-based taxation.

Comment: @M.Y.Zuo Depending how the scheme is structured, in the best case, the U.S. does not care if the heir does not ever visit the U.S.; in the worst case, it becomes criminal taxation fraud and the U.S. seeks extradition.

Comment: @M.Y.Zuo It would depend on the prosecutor (state or federal) and how much was involved. If it was an asset worth more than $12 million, like a yacht, and the IRS determined that there was tax evasion and the person owing the tax failed to appear, then criminal warrants would be issued and bench warrants for property seizure could be issued as well. US warrants often will translate to Europe.

Comment: In the US, both gift and inheritance taxes are paid by the "giver" (i.e. the person giving the gift or by the estate).  The gift or inheritance doesn't result in the receiver or heir having to pay tax (I believe some state taxes don't follow that rule).  Citizenship isn't important, "residence" is.  If you have a green card (i.e., you are a permanent resident alien - even if you are living outside the US), you have the same tax burden as a citizen.  And, if you give up permanent residence, the IRS kinda-sorta presumes that you did it to avoid taxation and will try to extract some flesh

Comment: @xngtng Can you elaborate? For example the heir is a Swiss citizen  living in some other country , who has not set foot in the U.S. for a year, how does the U.S. tax the movable property they just received after their late uncle passed away?

Comment: @Flydog57 In my example, the property is moved abroad and transferred to the heir, or stored in the foreign warehouse, etc., before the original owner is deceased.

Answer (score 0):

Let’s say your grandma owned a diamond ring worth 100,000. If you take it abroad after she dies to avoid inheritance tax, that’s tax evasion. If you move it before she dies, you might have to pay custom taxes, you may have to pay taxes for receiving a gift worth 100,000, you might have to pay inheritance tax abroad, and if you don’t tell other heirs who would like their share of the 100,000, that might be fraud or theft.

So I don’t see any reason not to have inheritance tax.

Comment: None of those apply if it's done in a country without inheritance taxes, import taxes on diamond rings, or gift taxes.